# AJAX Request Returns Doubled List of Objects - YUI

Tags: javascript, ajax, yui

I am using YUI's [Datatable Column Formatter](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/DataTable.Column.html#property_formatter) to format some data returned from an AJAX request. Here's the config:

```
var dataTable = new Y.DataTable(
{
    id: 'my-table',
    height: '500px',
    width: '500px'
});
var columns = [{
        key: 'id',
        label: 'ID'
    }, {
        label: 'Name',
        formatter: function (o) {
            console.log(o.data);
            return o.data.name; 
        }
    },
    {   
        key: 'department',
        label: 'Department'
    }
];

function search(){
    dataSource = new Y.DataSource.IO({source: '/search' });
    dataSource.sendRequest({
        dataType: 'json',
        on: {
            success: function(e) {
                response = e.data.responseText;             
                data = Y.JSON.parse(response);
                dataTable.set('columns', columns);
                dataTable.set('data', data.content); 
            },
            failure: function(e) {
                //do stuff
            }
        });
    }
```

My table gets populated fine

[image]

And this is returned from the console

```
Object {id: 1, name: "Bob", department: 001}
Object {id: 2, name: "Andy", department: 003}
```

However if I launch the request a second time, the number of Objects returned doubles

```
Object {id: 1, name: "Bob", department: 001}
Object {id: 2, name: "Andy", department: 003}
Object {id: 1, name: "Bob", department: 001}
Object {id: 2, name: "Andy", department: 003}
```

While the data still displays, this duplication breaks functionality elsewhere. Additionally, no matter the number of times the request is launched, only the doubled list returns. Any idea why the Objects are getting combined?

Comment: Try removing the existing data on each AJAX request. `$('#myTableID').remove()` and then recreate. It seems your AJAX call is appending to the existing content

Comment: @ctwheels that was indeed the correct answer. If you post it I will accept

Comment: Note that I had to move the `dataTable` declaration to inside of the `search` function to get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the existing data on each AJAX request. `$('#myTableID').remove()` and then recreate. It seems your AJAX call is appending to the existing content